# OR operator is not working in LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I need to select a list which is not contains grade 2 and grade 8 . Now all the items with grade 2 also selects. Please see below is my code

```
var subjectList = printViewModel.GetSubjects().Where(p => p.Grade != "2" || p.Grade != "8");
```

**PrintTemplateViewModel class**

```
public class PrintTemplateViewModel
{
    public List<SubjectsViewModel> lstSubjectsViewModel { get; set; }

    public List<SubjectsViewModel> GetSubjects()
    {
        return lstSubjectsViewModel;
    }
}

public class SubjectsViewModel  
{ 
    public string Grade { get; set; } 
}
```

Comment: Why do you have a `public List<SubjectsViewModel> GetSubjects()` method when you already have a `public List<SubjectsViewModel> lstSubjectsViewModel { get; set; }` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want `&&`, not `||`. No matter what the string value, it's always going to either not be "2" or not be "8". It can't be both at once! :)

Answer (score 0):

The "OR" is working fine. It is your logic that is not working :D

use `&&` because you want to check both values are true.